# Not able to change default starting page in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I create a web application in Netbeans, named test9. I have create various jsp files and servlets,etc in it.Now i want to change the starting page `index.html` to `index.jsp` so I created a new file `index.jsp` and deleted `index.html` but after running it, It is still trying to open `index.html` and displaying 404 error resource not found i even made changes in my xml file but still it is doing it.
Do i have to make some other changes ?

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
    <filter-name>RequestLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>bean.RequestLoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>bean.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RequestLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bean.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bean.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DepartmentServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bean.DepartmentServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>C_userServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bean.C_userServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>statusServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bean.statusServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bean.FileServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SearchServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bean.SearchServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NoCacheFilter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bean.NoCacheFilter</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>forgotServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bean.forgotServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>passServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bean.passServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LogoutServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DepartmentServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DepartmentServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>C_userServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/C_userServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>statusServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/statusServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FileServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SearchServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SearchServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NoCacheFilter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NoCacheFilter</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>forgotServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/forgotServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I hope you redeployed the application to server.

Comment: yes i did redeployed it.

Comment: Try clean & build project, then try to deploy the project. Your `web.xml` file seems to be fine.

Comment: nothing happened it is still trying to open index.html

Answer (score 0):

In netBeans you can right click button on your project, then properties. A new pop up window will open, and on the left menu there will be a label call run. Click there and then in the "relative URL" you should put

```
/nameOfYourJspFile.jsp
```

and it works but i still do not know why

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post but since i had the same issue and solved it i am posting my answer to help some others who might stuck in a situation like this.

What worked for me was to take the new jsp file out of the WEB-INF folder.